# ANT - Java ClassLoader cant find class

Tags: java, ant, classpath, classloader, classnotfoundexception

in my project there are - among others - two classes: TheProblem and Server.

```
public class TheProblem {
    public static void main (String args []) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("Server");
    }
}
```

When I execute the code from the command line, everything works just fine.
But when I use ANT to execute the code, I get a ClassNotFoundException - although both Server.class and TheProblem.class are inside of the same directory.

The directory structure of my project is fairly simple - I will try to illustrate it here:

```
root_folder/
- build.xml
- src/
    - TheProblem.java
    - Server.java
- build/
    - TheProblem.class
    - Server.class
```

Here is an excerpt of my build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<project name="JAXB" default="compile">

<path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}" />
    <pathelement location="build" />
 </path>

 <target name="init" >
    <mkdir dir="build" />
 </target>

 <target name="compile" depends="init" >
     <javac classpathref="project.class.path" srcdir="src" destdir="build"
         includeAntRuntime="false" />
 </target>

 <target name="execute-problem" depends="compile">
     <java classpathref="project.class.path" classname="TheProblem" />
 </target>

 <target name="clean" depends="init">
     <delete dir="build" />
 </target>
 </project>
```

When I execute *ant compile*, everything compiles, but when I execute *ant execute-problem*, the ClassLoader cannot find the Server class and throws a ClassNotFoundException.
When I navigate into the build directory and call *java TheProblem*, it works just fine. I really have no clue, why it doesn't work using ANT.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this post.

Comment: Use packages. They make classloading much easier and more reliable.

Comment: Still does not work, just put every class in a "main" package and still getting the same Exception. - However, running the program from the command line still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<target name="execute-problem" depends="compile">
         <java classpathref="project.class.path" classname="TheProblem" />
     </target>
```

try to use this

```
 <target name="execute-problem" depends="compile">
   <java fork="true" dir="." classname="TheProblem">
     <classpath>
      <path refid="project.class.path" />
     </classpath>
   </java>
 </target>
```

Comment: You might also want to add the attribute fork="true" to the <java> task - otherwise you will be executing code within the context of the Ant JVM. Might not cause any problems, but it's generally safer/less surprising to keep things isolated.

Comment: right,  <java fork="true" dir="." classname="TheProblem">

Comment: Thank you very much, fork="true" solved the problem.